# What C calls does mdls use?

Tags: macos, metadata, c

I am hoping to get `mdls` information from C calls, as I am using a different programme's FFI to make C calls.  (In particular, I am after the `kMDItemContentTypeTree` key.)  I have tried using [`getxattr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getxattr.2.html), however this does not return the same output.  I have tried looking to open source tools which might also use some FFI, such as [`osxmetadata`](https://github.com/RhetTbull/osxmetadata), but this appears to return the same output as `getxattr`.  I am specifically trying to avoid shell execution (such as the use of [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)).

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  The reason it was closed: "This question is not about computer hardware or software".  However, I am asking about the command line tool (i.e., _software_), mdls, and about the C programming language (which is also software).  I do not understand why this question about computer software was closed.

Comment: I guess because this may involve actual programming that it fits better over at StackOverflow.com rather than here? You may try asking over there, if you do, let me now by tagging me here and I'll try to answer. `getxattr` deals with extended attributes (metadata) attached to files. They're actually unrelated to ext. attrs.: `mdls` involves higher level stuff that makes calls into LaunchServices and uses the LS database. Look into `CoreServices/LaunchServices/UTType.h` or the UniformTypeIdentifier.framework.

Comment: Actually, I just used `nm /usr/bin/mdls` to see what symbols are in `mdls`. It looks like it uses `MDItemCopyAttributeNames()` and `MDItemCopyAttributes()` in the `CoreServices/Metadata.framework/MDItem.h` framework.

Comment: Thank you @NSGod.  I didn't know about the `nm` tool.  Your help (guiding me towards `MDItemCopyAttribute*` functions) has helped me to implement these functions in the language I was after.  I needed to implement `CFString*` functions as well, as that is what `MDItem*` functions expect to use for paths.